# I'm getting the surface area of a sphere, to be $2 \pi^2r^2$

Tags: area, surfaces, spheres

To visualize what I mean,
Let's say we take a bangle of circumference=$2 \pi r$.
Let's keep this on the floor, so that the bangle is along a plane perpendicular to the floor. 
Let's rotate the bangle.
Won't the 3d image formed, look like a sphere?

If we consider the amount of angle it has covered, it will be 2$\pi$ (we can only consider half of this, i.e, $\pi$ for the area of the sphere, since it covers the whole area, twice.)
So the length along which the bangle moves, would be $\pi$r, to form a sphere.

Hence, I'm getting the surface area, yo be= $2 \pi r*\pi r$
=$2 \pi^2r^2$

Edit: I have added 2 pictures to explain, what I mean

[image: The bangle rotating]
[image]

Comment: Compare what happens in a stripe near the equator with what happens with a stripe near the north pole. It is rather clear that the area of the latter is smaller than the area of the former.

Comment: Your calculation of the surface area is obviously wrong. What is it based on?

Comment: @uniquesolution Please see the pictures I have added, so that you may get an idea.

Comment: I know what you mean even without the nice photos. However, I also know what the surface area of a sphere is, and it is not what you got.

Comment: @uniquesolution let's consider the length of the bangle as a line of length-2(pi)r along the y-axis. Can we consider the rotation of the bangle as a sweeping along the x-axis?

Comment: @uniquesolution so a line of length 2(pi)r swept along (pi)r along the x-axis will make the surface area so? Or am I missing something here? If you haven't understood what I'm trying to say using these x and y axes, I may try to explain it to you again.

Comment: The stripe goes through two points on the equator, opposite to each other.(two points such that if you dig a hole from one, you reach the other point). The stripe is perpendicular to the equator. Also, please see the images I have added. I have assumed the bangle to be the stripe.